# Error "cannot access zzbfm" when I use a new version of Firebase Library

Tags: android, gradle

Currently I am using following versions:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
```

If I switch to

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
```

I am getting error during compilation:

```
  Error:(1032, 22) error: cannot access zzbfm
    class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfm not found
```

What is wrong with these libraries?

Also I use following library:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:11.8.0'
```

when Android Studio shows an error of  the Firebase Library, it jumps to code:

```
private MediaInfo buildMediaInfo() {
        MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_TV_SHOW);

        mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, clickedChannel.getName());

        String protectedURL = getURLwithSignature(selectedStreamingURL);
        appendLog(protectedURL);
        return new MediaInfo.Builder(protectedURL)
                .setContentType("application/x-mpegurl")
                .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE)
                .setMetadata(mediaMetadata)
                .build();
    }
```

It seems I should update com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework to 15.0.1 but version doesn't exist.

Comment: show your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @Muhammad Hannan, stackoverflow doesn't allow it

Comment: @Muhammad Hannan, added more details

Comment: I have a similar problem using Cordova. What's up with this message, if you just google "com.google.android.gms.internal" you notice a lot of zz* stuff like `zzaja`, `zzbej`, `zzbck`. What's all those?

Comment: @huggie I solved problem:) read below

Answer (score 0):

Updated this library

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework to 15.0.1
```

Comment: Quite unfortunately I'm not using the play-services-cast-framework.